# web2py: how to convert a string with symbols/letters to an integer without them?

Tags: string, integer, web2py, symbols

I would like to know if there is a way in web2py to take a string with characters other than numbers and convert it to an integer without those characters. I would like to be able to do something like this:

turn this string ('1a-2') to this integer (12)

Comment: Would be better if provided more examples for a clearer explaination

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to web2py, but something like:

```
import re
int(re.sub(r'\D', '', '1a-2'))
```

You might want to add some error checking, in case there are no integers in the string.